# Convert complex time string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

Attempting the following `pd.to_datetime('2020-08-29 18:00:09:438')` results in an error `ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2020-08-29 18:00:09:438')` .

How would I convert this string to a datetime or timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us pass the correct `format`

```
pd.to_datetime('2020-08-29 18:00:09:438', format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
Out[71]: Timestamp('2020-08-29 18:00:09.438000')
```